# How to handle null values when returning a List C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some issues trying to get a list that may have null values in the column that is used to `OrderByDesending`. I am working with data that is populated from a program that is used at the customer facility. I am trying to populate a list of appointments. I do not have the answer as to why there are appointments in the system with no dates other than maybe they are future appointments with dates not set yet. In most cases you would use  `public DateTime? ApptDate { get; set; }` But then on my Foreach on the view I cannot populate the date as a string because it is a nullable value. Also when doing the compare I have to do something funky like

```
 var date = DateTime.Now;
 var appd = item.ApptDate ?? date; /// or something like this           
 int result = DateTime.Compare(appd, date);`
```

In the View this will not work:  `@item.ApptDate.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")`

I think what I want to do is handle this as Appointments that are set and still show them. Maybe with an `if` `else` statement. Could someone shed some light on how to present the date when it does exist?

Current View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.ApptDate != null)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        var appd = item.ApptDate;

        int result = DateTime.Compare(appd, date);
        if (result > 0)
        {
            <div class="time-label">
                <span class="bg-success">
                    @item.ApptDate.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")
                </span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-tooth bg-primary"></i>
                <div class="timeline-item">
                    @{
                        var time = (item.TimeHr + ":" + item.TimeMin).AsDateTime();
                        var stdTime = time.ToShortTimeString();
                        var time2 = time.AddMinutes(item.ApptLength).ToShortTimeString();
                    }
                    <h3 class="timeline-header"> @stdTime - @time2 </h3>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        Appointment Added!
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Confirm</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reschedule</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }

}
```

Controller - for testing I have added hard numbers:

```
    public ActionResult Appointments()
    {
        //var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //var lookup = db.AppointmentView.Where(x => x.Id == user).FirstOrDefault();
        //return View(db.AppointmentView.Where(x => x.Id == user && x.FamilyId == lookup.FamilyId).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ApptDate));

        int familyid = 1618;
        int patientId = 1451;

        return View(db.AppointmentView.Where(x => x.PatientId == patientId && x.FamilyId == familyid && x.ApptDate != null).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ApptDate));
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured this out. Hope it is useful to someone else. Here is my new view and the controller was changed to load all records with a date or null..

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    var date = DateTime.Now;
    var appd = item.ApptDate ?? date;
    var dateOf = item.ApptDate != null ? item.ApptDate.Value.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy") : "N/A";

    int result = DateTime.Compare(appd, date);

    if (item.ApptDate == null)
    {
        <div class="time-label">
            <span class="bg-success">
                @dateOf
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-tooth bg-primary"></i>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                @{
                    var time = (item.TimeHr + ":" + item.TimeMin).AsDateTime();
                    var stdTime = time.ToShortTimeString();
                    var time2 = time.AddMinutes(item.ApptLength).ToShortTimeString();
                }
                <h3 class="timeline-header"> @stdTime - @time2 </h3>
                <div class="timeline-body">               
                   An appointment has been added but a date is not setup!
                </div>

                    <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Confirm</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reschedule</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    if (result > 0)
    {
        <div class="time-label">
            <span class="bg-success">
                @dateOf
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-tooth bg-primary"></i>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                @{
                    var time = (item.TimeHr + ":" + item.TimeMin).AsDateTime();
                    var stdTime = time.ToShortTimeString();
                    var time2 = time.AddMinutes(item.ApptLength).ToShortTimeString();
                }
                <h3 class="timeline-header"> @stdTime - @time2 </h3>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    Appointment has been Sheduled!
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Confirm</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reschedule</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

}
```